# How to show my date from back end to angular material date picker field?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular5

I have a form that fill from back end data all my filed are okay but the filed of birthday don't bring me back the date from back end. I am using angular material and Date picker.

I fill the form like this in my component

```
Birthday: [this.client.Birthday]
```

This is my filed in html

```
 <div class="mb-24" fxLayout="row">
          <mat-form-field fxFlex>
            <input matInput name="Birthday" [(ngModel)]="client.Birthday" formControlName="Birthday" placeholder="Ditëlindja"  [matDatepicker]="picker"   tabindex="13">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>

      </div>
```

How can i get my date from back end and show to my html, when i make put request my date go fine to back end and change the date, but when i want to see my date in update form they don't show. I think that problem is to `[matDatepicker]`

Comment: There's not enough information in the code you provided to identify an answer, but I'm guessing that you're not updating `Birthday`'s value when you get `client` from the back end.

Comment: Client(): Observable<Client[]> {
    return this._http.get<Client[]>('http://localhost:1636/BOXService.asmx/Client');   this is my call to get the client

Comment: You have `this.client.Birthday` as the default value of your `Birthday` FormControl. If `this.client` is null at the time the FormGroup is constructed, `Birthday`'s value will be undefined even _after_ data is returned from the back end. You'll need to do `this.myFormGroup.get('Birthday').setValue(client.Birthday);` in your subscription.